# How to align layout to center with full background?

Tags: css, layout

I have a full background layout but the position of the **white content box** has an unexpected position and it's not always centered on different screen resolutions. Should I make it liquid or elastic? Right now it's fixed.

I tried using a fixed width container for the content box in the middle and margin: 0 auto, but that didn't do anything

**See code**: http://avisuals.web.fc2.com/testexample.html

What should I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your Html and CSS.It would be more helpful.

Comment: I never understand how LOL. My bad

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change as per this in your css file style.css 
http://avisuals.web.fc2.com/style.css

```
#container{
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and remove margin from

```
#contentbox-top and #content1 and contentbox-bottom
```

ie

```
#contentbox-top {
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url(images/content_top.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
_background: none;
_filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=images/content_top.png,sizingMethod=crop);
width: 700px;
height: 37px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

#content1 {
margin: 0 auto;
background: url(images/content_middle.png) repeat-y center;
width: 692px;
position: relative;
}

#contentbox-bottom {
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url(images/content_bottom.png);
_background: none;
_filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=images/content_bottom.png,sizingMethod=crop);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 700px;
height: 37px;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This is PERFECTION. Thank you!

Comment: I did this but now the layout doesn't work in Internet Explorer :( Help!

Comment: add z-index after position in #contentbox-bottom,#content1

Answer (score 0):

Set the element that contains the element you want centered to have `text-align:center`. Then set the element you want centered to have a left and right margin of `auto`. Then anything above those needs to have a width that allows it to expand to the width of the screen. Set it to `width:auto` or simply omit the width property.

Looking at your site you want to center `#container` inside the body element. Make sure to also give `#container` the appropriate width.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue you have.I think you should just set `margin:0 auto`.You set `margin-top` and `margin-left` after  setting `margin:0 auto`.I think that might be causing the problem.

Check [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W7V6M/).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yeah I did it backwards :/ Thank you so much!